# How can I create a border in the middle of the div (horizontally)?

Tags: css, less, border

I have a line of objects/elements like this:

[image]

I want to create a line, and place it **behind** all my objects, in the  **center** if my div.

Here is what I'm hoping to make:

[image]

To create a border on top, right, bottom, left, or around a div is quite simple, but in the middle of the div is surprisingly hard. I've been trying to research on this, but I don't see any good one so far.

Any CSS expert want to show off your CSS skill?

[`Fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/bheng/1Leyhps6/)

Comment: are you asking to only create the horizontal line in the middle of the shapes?

Comment: Behind the shapes. In the middle of the div.

Comment: i guess the line cannot cross into the circle one.

Comment: Why's that ? Why can't we set the z-index to the lowest ?

Comment: oh, ok perhaps you should post a jsfiddle, so we can get started from there.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[**Codepen**](http://codepen.io/bretteast/pen/ZYPYav)

Give this a go:

html

```
<div></div>
```

css

```
div { width: 200px; 
  height: 200px; 
  border: red 1px solid;
  position: relative;
}

div:after { content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-right: 2px green solid;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
div:before { content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-bottom: 2px green solid;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
   }
```

Comment: Hi @rangerover.js I've updated the code and the pen to show both a horizontal and vertical line :) - unfortunately, I can't see the images on here from my work computer

Comment: Sure mate, check it here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BrettEast/twnhhmL2/) @rangerover.js

Comment: Thanks to your starter code. I be able to accomplish what I want [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bheng/1Leyhps6/5/)

Comment: Great, just lose the `translate` line and bump the `top:` upto `55%` and I think you'll have what you're after/

Answer (score 9):

[Here is your own updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BrettEast/twnhhmL2/)

```
.border-center { 
            width: 100%;
            border: red 1px solid;
            position: relative;
        }

.border-center:before { content: '';
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 50%;
        border-bottom: 2px green solid;
        width: 100%;
        z-index:0;
    }
```

Comment: Good idea about parent is relative and child is absolute, we can control this powerfully!